# Lucene search by URL

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, full-text-search

I'm storing a Document which has a URL field:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new Field("url", url, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
doc.add(new Field("text", text, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc.add(new Field("html", CompressionTools.compressString(html), Field.Store.YES));
```

I'd like to be able to find a Document by its URL, but I get 0 results:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30)
Query query = new QueryParser(LUCENE_VERSION, "url", analyzer).parse(url);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(index, true);
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(10, true);
searcher.search(query, collector);
ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
// Display results
for (ScoreDoc hit : hits) {
  System.out.println("FOUND A MATCH");
}
searcher.close();
```

What can I do differently so that I can store an HTML document and find it by its URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may rewrite your query to something like this

```
Query query = new QueryParser(LUCENE_VERSION, "url", analyzer).newTermQuery(new Term("url", url)).parse(url);
```

**Suggestion:**

I suggest you use BooleanQuery since it gives good performance and internally it is optimized.

```
TermQuery tq= new TermQuery(new Term("url", url));
// BooleanClauses Enum SHOULD says Use this operator for clauses that should appear in the matching documents.
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery().add(tq,BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(index, true);
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(10, true);
searcher.search(query, collector);
```

I see you are indexing using URL frield as Not_Analysed, which is good IMO for searching,  As no analyzer is used the value will be stored as a single term.

Now if your business case says, i will give you a URL find the **EXACT** one from the Lucene Index then you shall look at your indexing with a different analyzer(KeywordAnalyzer etc)

Answer (score 2):

The Lucene `QueryParser` is interpreting some of the `url` characters as part of the [Query Parser Syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/queryparsersyntax.html). You can use a `TermQuery` instead, like so:

```
TermQuery query = new TermQuery(new Term("url", url));
```