# Lucene 4.0 in text search

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using lucene 4.0 with java. I'm trying to search for a string inside a string. If we look at the lucene hello world example, I wish to find the text "lucene" inside the phrase "inLuceneAction". I want it to find me two matches in this case instead of one.

Any Idea on how to do it?

Thanks

```
public class HelloLucene {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
// 0. Specify the analyzer for tokenizing text.
//    The same analyzer should be used for indexing and searching
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);

// 1. create the index
Directory index = new RAMDirectory();

IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_40, analyzer);

IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
addDoc(w, "inLuceneAction", "193398817");
addDoc(w, "Lucene for Dummies", "55320055Z");
addDoc(w, "Managing Gigabytes", "55063554A");
addDoc(w, "The Art of Computer Science", "9900333X");
w.close();

// 2. query
String querystr = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "lucene";

// the "title" arg specifies the default field to use
// when no field is explicitly specified in the query.
Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_40, "title", analyzer).parse(querystr);

// 3. search
int hitsPerPage = 10;
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage, true);
searcher.search(q, collector);
ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;

// 4. display results
System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");
for(int i=0;i<hits.length;++i) {
  int docId = hits[i].doc;
  Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
  System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + d.get("isbn") + "\t" + d.get("title"));
}
// reader can only be closed when there
// is no need to access the documents any more.
reader.close(); 
}
private static void addDoc(IndexWriter w, String title, String isbn) throws IOException {
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new TextField("title", title, Field.Store.YES));

// use a string field for isbn because we don't want it tokenized
doc.add(new StringField("isbn", isbn, Field.Store.YES));
w.addDocument(doc);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you index the terms in the default way, meaning `inLuceneAction` is one term, Lucene won't be able to `seek` to this term given `Lucene` because it has a different prefix. Analyze this string so that it results in three indexed terms: `in` `Lucene` `Action` and then you'll have it fetched. You'll either find a ready-made analyzer for this or you'll have to write your own. Writing own analyzers is a bit out of scope for a single StackOverflow answer, but an excellent place to start is the package info at the bottom of the [org.apache.lucene.analysis](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/index.html) package Javadoc page.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm trying to do a simple url search. I cannot analyze the index term(it does not have structure). So what is the best way to do a url search?

Comment: Then you'll have to index all substrings: `inLuceneAction`, `nLuceneAction`, `LuceneAction`, ond so on. I think there's built-in support for this kind of indexing/queri, but don't remember from the top of my head.

Comment: it seems it was easier in version 3.0. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321388/lucene-search-by-url

Comment: No, that answer isn't solving anything; it just avoids the `QueryParser` and uses a `SHOULD` constraint, which means there is no `MUST` term at all; the query will return **all** documents, but if some happen to have an exact match on the URL, they will be on top.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I agree that it doesn't solve the problem here, but I believe you are mistaken in your comment.  If no `MUST` clause is present, at least one `SHOULD` clause must be matched.  Simply lacking a `MUST` clause will not cause a query to return all documents (returning all documents from a Lucene index isn't that simple).  The index will fetch documents found by term hits.  If no term matches, the index has no way to actually find the document at all.

Comment: Also, a good way to tokenize as in Marko's comment above, to enable effective `*term*` querying, is using [EdgeNGramTokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/EdgeNGramTokenizer.html).

Comment: @femtoRgon You are right, I had that at the back of my mind, but it slipped. A single `SHOULD` behaves as though it was `MUST`. But nevertheless, it *is* a straightforward operation to enumerate all docs, at least it was so in 3.x. Has that changed with 4?

Comment: @femtoRgon Regarding `EdgeNGramTokenizer`, OP should use `Side.BACK` and specify a large enough max n-gram size, I suppose.

Comment: If you are refering to a `MatchAllDocsQuery`, yes it's still around, but still not available from the QueryParser, to my knowledge.